# How to tie gridview Edit to an index - (GridViewEditEventArgs returns wrong argument)

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

Whenever I hit the Edit button it gets the wrong index from the form.  How would I tie the edit to the row it's on?

Here is the relevant part of the grid...

```
  <asp:GridView 

        ID="gvChart" 
        runat="server" 
        AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
        AllowPaging="True" 
        PageSize="100"
        EnableViewState="False" 
        DataKeyNames="ID" 
        onrowediting="gvChart_RowEditing"
        OnPageIndexChanging="gvChart_PageIndexChanging"
        OnRowDataBound="gv_RowDataBound">

       <Columns>

          <asp:TemplateField>
                <ItemTemplate>
                      <asp:Button ID="EditButton1" runat="server" CommandName="Edit"  Text="Edit"/>
            </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>

        </Columns>

    </asp:GridView>
```

The code behind is here. 'e' gets an incorrect 'NewEditIndex' value going in to the method.

```
protected void gvChart_RowEditing(object sender, GridViewEditEventArgs e)
{
    string ID = gvChart.DataKeys[e.NewEditIndex].Value.ToString();

}
```

Comment: I should add that if I remove the 'ORDER BY ID' from my query then the Edit button ties to the correct row. But I need it ordered by ID.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 string ID  = gvChart.DataKeys[e.RowIndex].Value;
```

Comment: e does not have a RowIndex property when I use it?

Comment: Refer to this article: http://www.webcodeexpert.com/2013/03/how-to-read-datakeynames-on-rowediting.html#.Uugd17RRWW8

Comment: That article uses RowIndex as well. :)    How do I get the GridViewEditEventArgs  object to acquire this property?